# knockout.js observablearray push not binding click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have some html as follows:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">        
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Empid"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Role"></td>
            <td>
                <a data-bind="click: editEmployee">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>            

    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="createForm">
    <input id="empidC" />
    <input id="nameC" />
    <input id="roleC" />
    <button type="button" id="insertEmployee">Create</button>
</div>
```

And I have a javascript file containing knockout code:

```
    $('#insertEmployee').click(function () {

        var empidC = $("#empidC").val(),
            nameC = $("#nameC").val(),
            roleC = $("#roleC").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Employees/Create",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "Empid": empidC, "Name": nameC, "Role": roleC }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

                // Data gets inserted in DB and alert statement is executing
                alert(msg);              

                eList.Employees.push({
                    Empid:empidC,
                    Name:nameC,
                    Role:roleC
                });

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

    });

    var getEmployees=function(){
        return $.get("/Employees/FetchEmployees");
    }

    //View Model for all Employees
    var EmployeeListVM = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.Employees = ko.observableArray();         

        getEmployees().done(function (data) {
            var emp = data.map(function (e) {
                return (new Employees(e));
            });
            self.Employees(emp);
        });

    };

    //Model for all Employees
    function Employees(data) {

        var self = this;

        this.Empid = ko.observable(data.Empid);
        this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.Role = ko.observable(data.Role);

        this.editEmployee = function (record) {

            var eEdit = new SingleEmployee(record);

            var cont = document.getElementById("editForm");
            ko.cleanNode(cont);
            ko.applyBindings(eEdit, cont);

            $("#editForm").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 450,
                title: "Edit Selected Record(s)"                
            });

            $("#editForm").dialog("open");           

        };

    }

    // Viewmodel for editing single record
    function SingleEmployee(data) {

        var self = this;
        this.Empid = ko.observable(data.Empid);
        this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.Role = ko.observable(data.Role);
    };

    var eList = new EmployeeListVM();
    ko.applyBindings(eList, document.getElementById("table"));
```

When I insert any new record in div "createForm", I get an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return editEmployee }"
Message: editEmployee is not defined

The new row is getting displayed, but the Edit link for that newly inserted record does not work

**EDIT:**

I solved the problem. The problem was that "Object" was getting passed to Employees(data) and not "Employees". So in the insertEmployee click, I changed code to:

```
            var newEmp = new Employees({
                Empid: empidC,
                Name: nameC,
                Role: roleC
            });

            eList.Employees.push(newEmp);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but you shouldn't be fiddling with the DOM outside of a binding handler.

Comment: @RoyJ I didn't get you

Comment: The way you're handling the click binding and the dialog with jQuery suggest a problem. Knockout has a `click` binding, and you should make a custom binding for the dialog. I don't know whether this is related to the error you're getting, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data actually getting to your server side controller and updating the DB? The ajax call to post data and call the Create method on the server, in the Success section assumes that all is ok on the server. All the success path does here is to say that the client side call was ok, It's not a server success. Where you currently have your alert statement, you need to ensure that the server side actually posted the data before attempting to retrieve it later in the refresh of the page.

Comment: The data is going to controller and getting updated in DB and the alert statement is executing

Comment: The 2 functions where you declare this.Empid = ko.observable(data.Empid); etc, Move these out to be on the main code block. You should only need to declare these as observable once, then knockout should keep track

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I had already edited the question and specified what the problem and its solution was